# How do I put my 2d animation on top of another video?

Tags: animation, transparency, 2d

I made a 2d animation that I want to put on top of another video. I can’t find a way to make the animation render with a transparent background. I tried setting the background as the video, but that did not render. Any tips/help?!

Comment: When I put my rendered video into the video editor, I can tell that it has a transparent background, but I can not see the video under it. Is there a way to enable the transparency/ make it so the gray square transparent background goes away?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Render properties -> Film -> transaparent  -> check this checkbox so you will get a transparent background.

Then you have to render your 2D animation again and put it together in the video sequencer.

[image]